# What is the preferred way to check for a Null pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, null, coding-style

Options A:

```
if (NULL == pSomethingColumn) // Yes, we use Yoda conditions
if (NULL != pSomethingColumn)
```

Or

```
if (pSomethingColumn)
if (!pSomethingColumn)
```

I am looking for references explaining the reasoning as well.

I have heard some people say that technically `NULL` does not have to be defined as `0`, but come on! if that was the case, then the sucker (our app) would crash in `-2147483648` different ways.

So, if `NULL != 0`, then we will have big problems.

Please help me settle a pointless syntax debate. I am not particularly attached to either way; just looking for the official way. Thanks.

P.S. We are using Visual Studio C++ compiler.

Comment: I'm quite sure `NULL` must be 0 on any conforming compiler.

Comment: @dreamlax, can you concoct a link/reference?

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan: C++ standard 4.10 "A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero." and 18.1 "The macro NULL is an implementation-defined C++ null pointer constant". The footnotes on the same page suggest that `0` and `0L` are valid for `NULL`, but not `(void *)0`.

Comment: @dreamlax: Actually it's `nullptr` in C++0x.

Comment: 18.1/4: "The macro NULL is an implementation-defined C++ null pointer constant in this International Standard (4.10)". However 4.10 says "A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type…" So 0 means NULL, but when it does, it is not necessarily bitwise 0.

Comment: @Billy:  One of those little C++0x changes I'm going to love.  Along with `auto`.

Comment: I feel it's important to point out that `nullptr` is just another null pointer constant in C++0x. `0` and `NULL` (which may or may not be something of type `nullptr_t` or might still be `0` dependending on the implementation) aren't going away.

Comment: You no longer need Yoda conditions in VS2005 and later, the compiler generates a warning if you miss one of the equal signs.

Answer (score 11):

I consider it an accident of history that zero corresponds to false and non-zero corresponds to true; I like to reserve those forms for boolean expressions only. However I don't have a problem with seeing that form in someone else's code.

My vote:

```
if (pSomethingColumn == NULL)
```

No, I've never been bitten by forgetting one of the equal signs. Just lucky, or maybe extremely careful.

Comment: Its also more natural to read this way and all modern compilers warn you if you accidentally do an assignment in an if statement (and since you (we/all of us) treat warnings as errors it will not compile) :-)

Comment: @Martin York, do you happen to know if Visual Studio 2010 C++ compiler (unmanaged and managed) warn you as well?

Comment: @Hamish: yes, but only at warning level 4.

Comment: I learned this week that gcc 4.3 does not warn, if you do the opposite: The line `charArr[0] == ' ';` does not result in a warning. (We were hunting a "string is always empty" bug).

Comment: @IanH: Yes it does, with `-Wall` I get `warning: statement with no effect.` Clang also produces a similar warning.

Answer (score 9):

Neither is clearly better than the other. From a technical standpoint they are equivalent. The number 0 in a pointer context does not mean all bits zero; it is defined to be equivalent to whatever bit pattern is used to represent null pointers. `NULL` can either be defined as `0` or `(void *) 0`. Either definition is syntactical and says nothing about the underlying bit representation.

So `if (!p)` is the same as `if (p == NULL)` is the same as `if (p == 0)` as far as technical correctness goes.

The issue is one of style. Like all style issues, your first inclination should be to match whatever the prevailing coding standards are. Do the same thing as the rest of the codebase. If there is no prevailing standard then it comes down to personal preference and you would be encouraged to develop a coding standard with your peers.

(Personally I like to use explicit comparisons and reserve the shorter syntax for boolean values, but I'll gladly use `if (!p)` that's what everyone else is doing.)

Comment: +1 for the recommendation to follow the herd. This is actually the most important consideration when your code will be shared with a group.

Comment: This is C++, `NULL` cannot be `(void*)0` otherwise initializations such as `int *p = NULL;` would be illegal.

Comment: Also `if (!p)` is equivalent to `if (p == 0)` not `if (p != 0)`.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ `NULL` has to be a null pointer constant in every implementation. `0` as a constant expression is always a null pointer constant (i.e. when converted to a pointer type it yields a null pointer value). Neither of these mean a null pointer value for any given pointer type has to be represented by an address that is zero or all bits zero but this is mostly academic from an application developer's point of view.

To use `NULL` you should `#include` a header that defines it such as `<cstddef>`; you can always use `0`.

When converted to a `bool` a null pointer value always converts to `false`; any other pointer value always converts to `true`.

When used as an argument to unary `!` a pointer value is converted to a `bool` as above and then negated.

So long as `NULL` is defined these are all equivalent:

```
if (NULL == pSomethingColumn)
if (pSomethingColumn == NULL)
if (0 == pSomethingColumn)
if (pSomethingColumn == 0)
if (!pSomethingColumn)
```

and these are all equivalent:

```
if (NULL != pSomethingColumn)
if (pSomethingColumn != NULL)
if (0 != pSomethingColumn)
if (pSomethingColumn != 0)
if (pSomethingColumn)
```

Answer (score 3):

Call me eccentric, but I actually prefer one from each set. I would use `if(ptr)` if I'm about to do something that specifically requires the pointer to exist. I would use `if(NULL==ptr)` if I'm about to do something that specifically requires the pointer to be NULL. I guess this stems from the theory that it's easier to read statements that are not negated.

The more the merrier...`if(!(0 != !ptr))`

Comment: Ah crap, you have just invented a third way.

Comment: personnally I tend to avoid the if(!ptr) because it happened more than once that I did not see the ! before ptr and so I guessed the test wrong. And when I see if(!(0 != !ptr)) I do a search in SVN to learn the name of the author, just to know if this psychopath is still around. :-)

Comment: By the way you could always do more psychopatically unreadable, what do you think about that ? : if(!(0 != !(ptr++)))

Answer (score 1):

You could probably find links to passionate arguments in favour of either one, but the only answer is: it doesn't matter. Both are correct, and either could be argued to be ever so slightly more expressive than the other, depending on your standards of expressiveness.

Regarding null pointers: while the *representation* of a null pointer is implementation-dependent, and isn't necessarily a value of zero, a *null pointer constant* is an integer constant with the value zero. So `NULL` must be defined as something that is convertible to an integer value of zero - the most obvious definition being `0`.

Comment: Hm ... maybe I should have asked - what does Google / MSFT use?

Comment: @Hamish: Google's style guide doesn't go into that level of irrelevent detail. Microsoft have had all sorts of wacky conventions over the decades, but I'm fairly sure their current conventions also don't worry about details like this. An enlightened style guide should give rules that lead to maintainable code, not specify how to write code down to the last character.

Comment: this is a good point. However, in the world of C# I happily follow StyleCop's rules which cover the most minute details, even if I disagree with 5% of them. I wish something like that existed for C++.

Comment: @Hamish: Such a tool would be useful for enforcing consistency, but (at least for me) that's a much less important quality than expressiveness and clarity. For the time being, the only tool that can check these is a human brain. Code reviews (or, at the very least, critical reading of your own code) will do more for quality than any style guide.

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer

```
  if (pSomethingColumn != NULL)
```

Not only because it is principally & conceptually correct, but also because it is *self-documenting*. Using a particular construct just because "it works" is a sure recipe for non-portability.

Comment: Thanks, and what is your take on Yoda conditions such as `if (NULL == x)` or `if (NULL != x)`?

Comment: I understand the benefits of the Yoda notation, but it doesn't feel natural to me so I haven't really adopted it. I like to read & write code that way I think, which is actually consistent with  my first answer.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is necessarily equal to `0` in any conforming C++ compiler. Personally, I prefer to use `NULL` because IMHO it's more explicit and the intent is clearer. But Bjarne Stroustrup [uses `0`](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#null) instead of `NULL` because he prefers to avoid macros. C++0x is going to have an explicit `nullptr` keyword that will hopefully eliminate this issue once and for all.

Answer (score 0):

I use (!pSomethingColumn) because I'm lazy, but (pSomethingColumn == NULL) is more expressive as it shows the variable is meant to be a pointer.

Comment: So does the fact that the variable is named `pSomethingColumn`.

Comment: @dreamlax, `pSomethingColumn` was given by me, the asker of this question. I have a habit of not revealing the exact variable names; that is how paranoid I am.

Comment: @dreamlax: That just means someone picked up a bad habit in the 1980s. Only the variable declaration will tell you what type it really is.

Comment: I have long said that the greatest crime in programming are committed attempting to save a few keystrokes -- just learn to friggin' type!

Comment: @James: Agreed, but one should also avoid extra keystrokes that don't add anything to the code. To me, pseudoHungarian warts and explicit comparisons with zero (especially when backwards written) can slightly reduce clarity, by adding noise but little information. And sometimes, if the wart isn't updated when the type changes, or someone uses `NULL` when they mean `0`, such conventions become actively misleading.