# Understanding Zero and NULL in C++

Tags: c++, garbage-collection

while searching for an answer as to whether I should use Zero or Null, I came upon this one in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577580/using-null-in-c) here on SO from a user stroustup:

> Should I use NULL or 0? In C++, the definition of NULL is 0, so there
>   is only an aesthetic difference. I prefer to avoid macros, so I use 0.
>   Another problem with NULL is that people sometimes mistakenly believe
>   that it is different from 0 and/or not an integer. In pre-standard
>   code, NULL was/is sometimes defined to something unsuitable and
>   therefore had/has to be avoided. That's less common these days.

So NULL and 0 are the same that's cool. But I need a little more understanding here: Suppose I have the following (a random example from [cprogramming.com](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson15.html)):

```
struct node {
  int x;
  node *next;
};

int main()
{
  node *root;       // This won't change, or we would lose the list in memory
  node *conductor;  // This will point to each node as it traverses the list

  root = new node;  // Sets it to actually point to something
  root->next = 0;   //  Otherwise it would not work well
  root->x = 12;
  conductor = root; // The conductor points to the first node
  if ( conductor != 0 ) {
    while ( conductor->next != 0)
      conductor = conductor->next;
  }
  conductor->next = new node;  // Creates a node at the end of the list
  conductor = conductor->next; // Points to that node
  conductor->next = 0;         // Prevents it from going any further
  conductor->x = 42;
}
```

Looking at the `while ( conductor->next != 0)` line for example; It is my understanding that that spot in memory could have garbage values in it from previous use. When it is released from use by a program, it becomes available again. So how can you use integer zero as a value to compare against in order to check if you have reached the end of the linked list? Can you guarantee that that garbage value is zero? Why wouldn't it be...just a random garbage value?

So, is my understanding completely off, or in the midst of the process of releasing that block of memory by a previous program is that memory re-zeroed? In the past I have always used NULL, thinking that it was a magic keyword that knew whether it was looking at a zero or a garbage value. However, reading the above answer to someone else's question I see that is not true. I apologize for such a trivial question but every time I compare against NULL or zero in my applications to check for the existence of something it bothers me that it just works and I don't know why. Thank you for any light you can shed.

Comment: in your example, it makes an assumption that when the object is freed, the corresponding pointer is set to NULL or 0 immediately by the developer. If it's not done, then you are correct, until the program terminates, that particular location will contain garbage values and in most cases, these are sources of heap corruption.

Comment: The 0 gets converted to NULL by the compiler, just like `true` and `false` in C++ can be interchanged with `1` and `0`

Comment: *In C++, the definition of NULL is 0*... well, `nullptr` is here now.

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup has stated that there is no need for NULL in a correctly written C++ program. @ShreyanShet That's not correct. It gets treated as a special value indicating a null pointer, but there is no such thing internally as NULL to convert it to. Indeed, NULL is just a macro for zero, so it would be be more accurate to state the opposite conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Stroustrop is not just "a user"; he is the original author and inventor of the C++ language. This quote is from one of his [Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html).

NULL in nearly all C and C++ implementations is just a #define (textual replacement) for 0. So the difference **is** purely aesthetic.

There is no magic. Perhaps you are not understanding the "next" pointer. It is the address of the next item, not the item itself. Since there is no valid pointer of 0, it is a convenient sentinel, or marker, to say there is no next item in the list. If a node is removed, nothing automatically sets the pointers to it (i.e. the next pointer located in the prior node) back to NULL/0.