# Are 'null' and 'NULL' the same?

Tags: c++, c

Are both null and NULL constants the exact same thing in C/C++?

I've noticed as I write my code in Visual Studio that null and NULL don't get the same syntax highlighting, and the compile outcome is not the same as having null instead of NULL in some sections of the code.

Comment: There is no "C/C++", they are different languages and behave differently in this case. Please narrow down your question to one specific language. Also, what is `null`, Java?

Comment: "and the compile outcome is not the same as having null instead of NULL in some sections of the code" I think you answered your own question

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577580/using-null-in-c

Comment: To make things perfectly clear, C has null pointers, null pointer constants, the NULL macro and null termination. All meaning different things. The integer constant `0` can be any of them. We may write it as `00` or `\0` as well, which is octal notation. We always use octal notation when referring to null terminators, because we can - there exists no rationale why. You can also just as well use hex `0x0` or `\x0`, it means exactly the same thing as all of the above, but if you do, I will no longer have a clue what you are referring to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They might be, they might not be.

Both C and C++ define `NULL`, but in slightly different ways.

`null` is not part of either standard; it is neither a keyword nor a reserved word, so you can use it as a variable name, class name &c..

The preferred way of denoting pointer null-ness in C++ is `nullptr` which has type especially designed for pointer nullness.

Comment: You can find `null` under the sea

Comment: @SombreroChicken: You can also find it in my office on a Friday afternoon.

Comment: @SombreroChicken and `seanulls` at the shore

Comment: I've found a nice picture with a toilet paper roll, explaining what null vs empty can be  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Assuming the paper roll is fresh, might you be able to upload a picture?

Comment: I don't want any paper rolls near me

Comment: @Bathsheba https://i.redd.it/3370lkxk56ny.jpg (you need the title of the reddit post for context , https://www.reddit.com/r/geek/comments/6128y3/amusing_example_between_0_and_null_0_on_the_left/)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: The one on the left can be a real tempter if that's all you have.

Comment: @Bathsheba well, if you can manage too peel the cardboard off... But this is starting to go off-topic as per "discussions that don't involve tools *primarily* used for programming"

Answer (score 2):

C standard says :

> **6.3.2.3/3 Pointers**
>
> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such expression
>   cast to type `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*.

`stddef.h` then contains the `NULL`-define to that value.

C++ (another language, roughly related to C, certainly not in the way people usually think) used `NULL` in its very early versions (don't use it!). But in pre-C++11 releases, the constant `0` was defined as the way to represent pointers to nothing. Alas, this has some serious drawbacks and then C++11 defined the `nullptr` constant. Note that `nullptr` is a **keyword**.

C++ standard says:

> **2.14.17/1 Pointer literals**
>
> The pointer literal is the keyword `nullptr`. It is a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. [ Note: `std::nullptr_t` is a distinct type that is neither a pointer type nor a pointer to member type; rather, a prvalue of this type is a null pointer constant and can be converted to a null pointer value or null member pointer value.]
>
> **3.9.1/10 Fundamental types**
>
> A value of type `std::nullptr_t` is a null pointer constant. Such
>   values participate in the pointer and the pointer to member
>   conversions. `sizeof(std::nullptr_t)` shall be equal to
>   `sizeof(void*)`.

About `NULL` in C++ standard says:

> **18.2/3 Types**
>
> The macro `NULL` is an implementation-defined C++ null pointer constant.

Comment: This is not *quite* complete. C++ *must* define NULL, but it is **not** allowed to define it as `(void*)0`.

Answer (score 0):

C language has a `NULL` but there is no `null`. `NULL` is used to
indicate the macro defined in  and when discussing pointers.

use `null` when discussing the `null` character. `null` character refers to `'\0'`.

With that semantics out of the way, if you are asking for the difference
between `(x == '\0')` and `(x == NULL)` it would depend on what `x` is.
Use `(x == '\0')` if `x` is a `char` or `int` and `(x == NULL)` if `x` is
a pointer.
For everything else you'd have to consider whether the
comparison is valid and how things will be converted or promoted.

Comment: Indeed , it is the ASCII associated to it. But '\0' is not the same as '0'.

Comment: "use (x == NULL) if x is a pointer" is not the right suggestion for c++ anymore

Comment: No that's not correct. In C, `'\0'` is *exactly* the same as 0 (both `int` types). In C++ the former is a `char` type, the latter an `int` type. Even more of a fun fact for the pub: 0 is an *octal* literal / constant.

Comment: Null termination is often referred to as "nul" just to not mix it up with null pointers.